# Converting PyTorch custom loss function to Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to convert Pytorch code into tensorflow code.
Here is the [Original code](https://github.com/JDE65/CustomLoss/blob/main/util_customloss_torch.py)

```
# original Pytorch code
class AdjMSELoss2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AdjMSELoss2, self).__init__()
                
    def forward(self, outputs, labels):
        outputs = torch.squeeze(outputs)
        beta = 2.5
        loss = (outputs - labels)**2
        adj_loss = beta - (beta - 0.5) / (1 + torch.exp(10000 * torch.mul(outputs, labels)))
        loss = beta * loss /(1+adj_loss) 
        return torch.mean(loss)
```

The below what i think it converts to...

```
# My attempt to convert them into tensorflow
def customLoss02(labels, outputs):
  beta = 2.5
  loss = (outputs - labels)**2
  adj_loss = beta - (beta - 0.5) / (1 + tf.math.exp(10000 * outputs * labels))
  loss = beta * loss / (1 + adj_loss)
  return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

model.compile(loss=customLoss02, optimizer='adam')
```

But, it does not train...

Epoch 1/3
122/122 - 8s - **loss: nan - val_loss: nan** - 8s/epoch - 67ms/step

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, it turns out that 10000 is the problem. The author of the custom loss function assumed that y * yhat will result in something like 0.0001 and multiplying 10000 back would help model learn quickly. But for my data, y * yhat was much larger and multiplying it by 10000 would make the model not learn.

```
(1 + tf.math.exp(10000 * outputs * labels))
```

```
def customLoss02(labels, outputs):
  beta = 2.5
  loss = (outputs - labels)**2
  adj_loss = beta - (beta - 0.5) / (1 + tf.math.exp(10 * outputs * labels))
  loss = beta * loss / (1 + adj_loss)
  return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

model.compile(loss=customLoss02, optimizer='adam') // works
```